# Pointer to constant string in struct

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct, constants

I'm writing in C.

In `header1.h` I declare a pointer to a constant string (a constant array of `char`), a new type with a struct and a variable of this type, and another variable:

```
const char *str_ptr = "Hello world!";

struct entry_t {
const char *text;
int var;
};
typedef entry_t entry;

extern entry start_entry;

int a;
```

In the file `func.c` I define the new variable:

```
#include "header1.h"

entry start_entry = {str_ptr, a};

void func(void)
{
    //here i use start_entry
}
```

But the compiler report me the error

> constant expression required

referring to the initialization of `start_entry`, and in particular of the `const char*` member.
Why? Where is the error?

Naturally if I define the string as

```
const char str[] = "Hello world!";
```

and then the `entry` variable as

```
entry start_entry = {&str, a};
```

everything is ok.

**EDIT_1**

I've made two errors in reporting my code:

1. var is `const` too

   struct entry_t {
   const char *text;
   const int var;
   };
2. in func.c *entry* is `const` too

   const entry start_entry;

**EDIT_2**

I don't care of *var*, my interest is on `const char *` member (even if maybe the problem is the same: i write wrong code before, also with `int var` i had an error...).
I'm going to redefine all:

```
//header1.h

const char *str_ptr = "Hello world!";

struct entry_t {
const char *text;
};
typedef entry_t entry;

extern const entry start_entry;


//func.c
#include header1.h

const entry start_entry = {str_ptr};

void func(void)
{
    //here i use start_entry
}
```

I can't understand why *start_entry* has a `const char*` member, i define it with a `const char*` but there is that error.

Comment: It looks like you are using a C++ compiler. In C there is no definition for `entry_t` by itself in the source shown.

Comment: Please, provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I bet you are using a non-gcc compiler right? can you tell us which compiler you are using?

Comment: `entry start_entry = {&str, a};` is an error, `&str` is the wrong type

Comment: There is another potential bug in your code; if two different .c files include `header.h` then there are multiple definitions of `a` and `str_ptr`.  They either need to be `static`, or have `extern` declarations only in the header.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre : I'm using XC8, the Microchip compiler.

Comment: @M.M : why `&str` is the wrong type? This is my problem?

Comment: @M.M :  if i use extern on *str_ptr* and *a* is right?

Comment: `const` does not mean "constant". `const` means read-only. A *constant* expression is one that can be (and in some cases must be) evaluated at compile time.

Comment: @KeithThompson : Ok. I think it be can evaluated at compile time, but i can't modify it at run time (it's read-only). But i need to initialize it: how can i do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with a C compiler you cannot initialize such statements in the global scope, it is considered as code outside a function:
(the same way that you cannot call a function to get tis return value and initialize a global outside a function)

```
entry start_entry = {str_ptr, a};
```

`str_ptr` is not really considered as a constant in C since it is seen as a pointer. The `const` qualifier does nothing here.

(the problem also occurs for me with `a` BTW, it looks that you are using some strange C++ compiler or a special C99 option see pmg comment)

When simply calling `g++`, your example works.

**Note about your "naturally" statement**:

```
entry start_entry = {&str, a};
```

compiles (with your compiler, gcc still rejects it because of `a`) but since you pass the *address* of the pointer, not the pointer itself => unspecified behaviour: not good.

If you want to do that, I suggest that you use a C++ compiler.

What works with simple gcc call:

```
char str_ptr[] = "Hello world!";
entry start_entry = {str_ptr, 12}; // considered as an array, value decided by the compiler, even if const keyword is missing
```

What doesn't

```
const char *str_ptr = "Hello world!";
entry start_entry = {str_ptr, 12}; // str_ptr is considered as a variable pointer even if const

entry start_entry = {"Hello world!", a}; // a is a variable: nocantdo
```

Where you are right is that `char []` tells the compiler that the pointer is constant, even without the `const` keyword BTW, whereas the `const` keyword is not taken into account.

Notes:

I had to fix your code so it compiles with my gcc compiler:

```
typedef struct  {
const char *text;
int var;
} entry;

extern entry start_entry;
```

Another point is: avoid declaring globals in header files as you'll get multiple inclusions or undefined symbols if you have more than one code file including it.

Comment: "char [] tells the compiler that the pointer is constant"  - no, there is no pointer involved

Comment: "entry start_entry = {&str, a};
works but not as you expect, since you pass the *address* of the pointer, not the pointer itself!" " - *str* is not defined as a pointer, so shouldn't i pass its address to the pointer of *start_entry*?

Comment: @BzFr `entry start_entry = {&str, a};` doesn't work, it is a constraint violation

Comment: @M.M : Why? How can initialize correctly the variable *start_entry*?

Comment: I meant `entry start_entry = {&str, a};` compiles, well with your compiler (because gcc won't take a as it's not constant), but will crash when executing.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use compile-time constants in initializers. The variable *str_ptr* is not even a run-time constant. What the `const` qualifier does is to prevent the string pointed to by *str_ptr* from being modified. The pointer itself can be reassigned. Therefor you need to initialize your start entry in an initialization function instead:

```
#include "header1.h"

entry start_entry;

void func(void)
{
    //here i use start_entry
}


void init(void)
{
    start_entry.text = str_ptr;
    start_entry.var = a;
}
```

Comment: Or preferably just use an array rather than the useless pointer variable.

Comment: This kind of init code should be highly frowned upon because it's rarely thread-safe and adds unnecessary runtime costs, especially if you fix the thread safety issues.

Comment: But if start_entry is `const`, like in EDIT_1, i can't initialize it.